# Detect/infer visitor base currency using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, currency

Is there a reasonable way to detect or infer the visitor's base currency using Javascript?

I'm thinking of using IP geolocation and timezone detection. Do you know of any existing libraries / methods for this, or alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it purely with JavaScript that I know of.

- I think the easiest way is to invoke a server-side script which determines currency based on the Accept-Language header, using your scripting-langauge of choice's localization functions.  Using Accept-Language for anything more than language is debatable though.  Personally I think it's fine, as long as you provide the visitor with a way to switch currencies.
- IP geolocation may also be a viable alternative, but I'm not entirely sure how accurate this would be throughout the world.  Again, just be sure to provide the visitor with a way to switch currencies.

Comment: Hadn't thought of Accept-Language, good idea. Wouldn't distinguish between multiple countries that use the same language though (eg. Spain and Mexico).

Comment: I ended up using IP geolocation and from the country figuring out the currency.

Answer (score 1):

afaik there is no way to get the user's IP or any other "geolocation" information with javascript.  However, you can get their local timezone offset by using `.getTimezoneOffset()`